# Correct behaviour of -Dfoo="bar" in Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've noticed the following disparity between using two different versions of Tomcat when setting system properties using -D.

If I pass in -Dfoo="bar" into Tomcat, and then look up the value of the 'foo' system property, I get different results depending on which version of Tomcat I use.

Tomcat 7.0.37:

```
System.getProperty("foo") returns "bar" (with quotes)
```

Tomcat 7.0.27:

```
System.getProperty("foo") returns bar (without quotes)
```

What is the 'correct' behaviour of this and should a bug be raised?

For reference, I'm doing this on AWS Elasticbeanstalk, so it's using 64-bit architecture and AWS's default Image. AWS sets the parameters automatically form me via a nice web UI so I can't just pass in -Dfoo=bar as that is hidden from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with Tomcat itself but with the upgrade process in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. You can find an explanation and suggested solutions in [this AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=460080).

Comment: David - thanks. That answers it perfectly. It's a shame that it's so hard to find (I couldn't find that question when trying to diagnose the problem in the first place!)